# What is the word for "technical usurpation of an old word"?

Tags: word-usage, terminology, technical

Is there a word for "usurpation, rather than merely borrowing, of an old word by later, technical usage"?  If so, what is it?

For example, of old, the English word *summer* meant "that season of the year in which the sun shines most directly; the warmest period of the year"; or even of older, as our own Peter Shor [observes,](http://www.wyrdwords.vispa.com/heathenry/calendar.html) "the half-year from around April to September."   However, if you use the word today in its ancient senses, it may not be long before someone earnestly corrects you to the effect that "summer" did not start until the solstice, about June 21.

Meghan Barr, Associated Press, June 19, 2012:

> NEW YORK—The official start of summer brought temperatures in the
>   high 90s to the Eastern Seaboard on Wednesday....

One does not wish to be too unkind to a busy staff reporter, perspiring at her desk, hurriedly churning pages of copy!  However, the adjective "astronomical" was, of course, available to Ms. Barr in place of the vague "official."  Now, Ms. Barr (as one suspects) and I both agree that her audience would have found "astronomical" jarring in this context; but, you see, that's my point.

Other old words that have suffered as *summer* has might include nouns like *force, energy* and *power,* adjectives like *energetic* (but oddly not *forceful* or *powerful*), verbs like *to dissolve,* and so on.  Our own FumbleFingers notes the noun *train,* whose older meanings the heedless locomotive seems to have hauled away.

The word *metaphor* indicates the borrowing, but does not imply the usurpation.  Is there a word (most likely a word from the Greek, one supposes) that also implies the usurpation?

Comment: The English word *summer* [originally](http://www.wyrdwords.vispa.com/heathenry/calendar.html) meant the half-year from around April to September.

Comment: You must move in _extremely_ (misguidedly) pedantic circles if ‘corrections’ that summer only starts at the summer solstice are commonplace—or even existent at all—for you. Summer _is_ just the warmest period of the year in normal language usage. Not sure how _force_, _energy_, and _power_ don’t just retain their old, generic meanings, either, in addition to more technical meanings they have developed alongside the original ones.

Comment: This is a good question, and the definition of the desired word is quite clear. However, it might help us find or coin a word for it if better examples were given. Personally. I'm going to look for an old word I can reuse for this purpose. :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet:  Meghan Barr, Associated Press, June 19, 2012: "NEW YORK -- The official start of summer brought temperatures in the high 90s to the Eastern Seaboard on Wednesday...."

Comment: @thb As I said, misguided. Summer has no ‘official’ start and end date, unless you’re specifically talking about _astronomical_ summer (which doesn’t even seem to fit very well with that quote, ’cause it started the on 6:09 PM on the day after the date given, and the quote uses past tense).

Comment: @Thb, what Janus was said was that the normal, everyday use of "the warm part of the year" is still in common use and full force in everyday speech, and lives alongside the more technical meaning (which is why, in fact, Ms. Barr had to *qualify* the "start of summer" with "*official*", because otherwise she risked being I misunderstood by her audience, as meaning "Late May when the weather started getting nice"). In other words, the word "summer" has not been *usurped*, it merely has two meanings which coexist (like "theory" in science vs the vernacular).

Comment: Also, _summer_ has a third definition: the meteorological one, whereby summer starts on 1 June and ends on 31 August. This usage is more common in some parts of the world than the astronomical one; but the original, vague usage is still more common than either in normal, everyday speech.

Comment: @DanBron:  Fair enough.  My examples may indeed not suffice.  Or, perhaps, the thing of which I speak exists only in my imagination!  Still, nothing especially prevented our Ms. Barr from preferring "astronomical" to "official," unless it was that she believed that her audience would accept only the astronomical definition as somehow wholly proper.

Comment: +1 for "Summer has no 'official' start and end date." Often here in the U.S. it's seen as the period between Memorial Day (the last Monday in May) and Labor Day (the first Monday in September). For schools it can be, roughly, the months of July and August. In northern Alaska, it's probably the period in late June, early July when pond hockey sucks.

Comment: Hi @Janus.  That makes little sense.  Peter's point is:  summer used to mean **about half the year** and it now means **about one quarter of the year**.  Very straightforward.

Comment: @Joe I’m not sure what you’re referring to as making little sense? I quite agree with Peter (and when I say ‘original’, I just mean ‘non-technical’, whether it refers to half the year or a quarter of it). My last comment was just to emphasise that there’s both the generic summer, the astronomical summer, and the meteorological summer, all of them existing side by side.

Comment: I .. don't know, I'm confused now by all the comments  :)  possibly in your 1e comment above it seemed like you were referring to PeterShor.  Anyways .. enjoy this late summer weekend!  vendange!

Comment: Janus _ I put it to you on this question that the OP's error is that "usurpation" is by far too strong.  the question (and it's a good one) is just "what do you call it when a general word gains a new more technical or precise meaning?"  (I don't know, what's the word for that?)

Comment: @JoeBlow:  Good point.  What weaker word might suit in place of "usurpation"?

Comment: @PeterShor:  I have integrated your six-month-summer observation into the question.  The web page to which you have linked is most interesting.  Thank you.

Comment: hi @thb dude.  I don't know _ I'm drunk now.  Pls ask Janus. You can trust Janus.

Comment: You all seem to be ignoring summer in the southern hemisphere...

Comment: I've never come across ***usurp*** in this context before (but I don't think I've ever come across such a "peevish pedant" as this OP either! :). The most common verbs I hear for using an existing word in a new sense are ***co-opt*** and ***appropriate***. But even if a term existed before, if it's used with a completely new meaning, it's still a ***neologism*** (defined as [a new word or a new use for an old word](http://www.yourdictionary.com/neologism?no-cache)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I do not mind if you and some others mean something different, but when I wrote the post, I actually meant "usurp."  I do not know another, suitable verb for the concept.

Comment: @thb: The scare quotes, exclamation mark, and smiley were all supposed to take the edge of any suggestion of personal animosity. FWIW, I think the question itself is just fine (even though I don't actually *know* any Greek-based grammatical/literary term, there might well be one). But I just think your "summer" is a terrible example. Better might be something like ***train*** (in the sense of *locomotive*).

Comment: @Drew:  I thought of that.  Avoided mentioning it only to avoid pedantry, since I supposed that everyone knew about the hemispheres already.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  My mistake.  I should don my reading glasses.  I missed the :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have added your *train* to the question.

Comment: @thb: I just though of a much better (and much more recent) example. We're always hearing references to [*"a quantum leap forward"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+quantum+leap+forward%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but if my physics serves me aright, that should mean the *smallest possible* advance, not a really big one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Fair enough.  If you have time, please feel free to edit the question as you see fit.  Your ideas are probably better than mine.

Comment: southern hemisphere? I'm shocked that the unusual tropication of planets in certain binary systems has not been considered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers --"quantum" drives me nuts because:  what it **ACTUALLY MEANS** is: **"STEPWISE, not smoothly"**. that is ALL it means.  HOWEVER, unfortunately people sometimes point out (as you have here) that "it once meant small, but now means big!"  It DOES NOT mean small, and DOES NOT mean big.  (Recall -- Einstein -- direct quote "everything's fucking relative, there is no small and big")  it just means in "stepwise" chunks: so for example **car gears** are, very simply, quantum.  (there's only 1, 2, 3 etc, not "2.73")  whereas "car speed" is not quantum (it's smooth).

Comment: Also banana plants "not being trees", raspberries "not being fruit", &c.

Comment: When accepted definitions (and there _are_ various accepted definitions for 'summer') conflict, the conflicting definitions are termed 'stipulative definitions'.  And if senses are found defined (uncaveated) in respected dictionaries, they're legitimate, like it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might suggest:

> ***coopt***:
>   to use or take control of (something) for your own purposes <sub><sup>[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/co-opt)</sup></sub>
>
> To take or assume for one's own use; appropriate <sub><sup>[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/co-opt)</sup></sub>

or in extreme cases

***redefine****:

1. to define (as a concept) again, reformulate;  *had to redefine their terms*
2. to reexamine or reevaluate especially with a view to change
   <sub><sup>[<sup>*</sup>From Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redefine)</sup></sub>

I think these definitions are especially applicable when something new is invented that needs a name and an existing word is coopted for that purpose.  *Computer* comes to mind where this used to mean a person who performed computations.  I've seen pictures of a room full of women all sitting at desks parallel processing.

Comment: co-opt is an outstanding idea, good one

Answer (score 4):

"[Specialization](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/Specialization.aspx#2-1O29:SPECIALIZATION-full)" or "Semantic Narrowing" - "A process of SEMANTIC CHANGE in which narrowing occurs in the meaning of a word..."